# Ubuntu 16.04 Xorg crash with the error: Failed to query NVIDIA devices

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg

After a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04.4, I have the following problem:
While I'm working on it, suddenly Xorg crashes and logout the system.
After I login, Ubuntu reported the following internal error:

```
-- Logs begin at Δευ 2018-06-11 09:08:12 EEST, end at Δευ 2018-06-11     11:39:50 EEST. --
 Ιούν 11 09:08:12 capdi kernel: ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
 Ιούν 11 09:08:12 capdi kernel: ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: View and update with x86_energy_perf_policy(8)
 Ιούν 11 09:08:12 capdi kernel: PCCT header not found.
 Ιούν 11 09:08:12 capdi kernel: (NULL device *): hwmon_device_register()    is deprecated. Please convert the driver to use hwmon_device_register_with_info().
 Ιούν 11 09:08:13 capdi kernel: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
 Ιούν 11 09:08:24 capdi systemd-udevd[296]: unknown key 'BUS' in /etc/udev/rules.d/ft-rockey.rules:1
 Ιούν 11 09:08:24 capdi systemd-udevd[296]: invalid rule '/etc/udev/rules.d/ft-rockey.rules:1'
 Ιούν 11 09:08:24 capdi systemd-tmpfiles[349]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf:14] Duplicate line for path "/var/log", ignoring.
 Ιούν 11 09:08:24 capdi kernel: wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:01: WQBC data block query control method not found
 Ιούν 11 09:08:24 capdi kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047F (\PMIO) (20170531/utaddress-247)
 Ιούν 11 09:08:24 capdi kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20170531/utaddress-247)
 Ιούν 11 09:08:24 capdi kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000055F (\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.GPIO) (20170531/utaddress-247)
 Ιούν 11 09:08:24 capdi kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20170531/utaddress-247)
 Ιούν 11 09:08:24 capdi kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000055F (\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.GPIO) (20170531/utaddress-247)
 Ιούν 11 09:08:24 capdi kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20170531/utaddress-247)
 Ιούν 11 09:08:24 capdi kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000055F (\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.GPIO) (20170531/utaddress-247)
 Ιούν 11 09:08:24 capdi kernel: lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
 Ιούν 11 09:08:25 capdi kernel: nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
 Ιούν 11 09:08:25 capdi kernel: nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
 Ιούν 11 09:08:25 capdi kernel: Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
 Ιούν 11 09:08:25 capdi kernel: NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  340.104  Thu Sep 14 17:13:13 PDT 2017
 Ιούν 11 09:08:25 capdi nvidia-persistenced[772]: Failed to query NVIDIA devices. Please ensure that the NVIDIA device files (/dev/nvidia*) exist, and that user 125 has read and write permissions for those files.
 Ιούν 11 09:08:25 capdi kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20170531/nsarguments-95)
 Ιούν 11 09:08:25 capdi kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20170531/nsarguments-95)
 Ιούν 11 09:08:25 capdi kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20170531/nsarguments-95)
 Ιούν 11 09:08:25 capdi kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20170531/nsarguments-95)
 Ιούν 11 09:08:25 capdi kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20170531/nsarguments-95)
 Ιούν 11 09:08:25 capdi kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20170531/nsarguments-95)
 Ιούν 11 09:08:25 capdi kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20170531/nsarguments-95)
 Ιούν 11 09:08:25 capdi kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20170531/nsarguments-95)
 Ιούν 11 09:08:25 capdi kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20170531/nsarguments-95)
 Ιούν 11 09:08:27 capdi kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20170531/nsarguments-95)
```

The output of the command:

```
ls -ld /dev/nvidia*; file /dev/nvidia*
```

is:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 195,   0 Ιούν 11 09:08 /dev/nvidia0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 195, 255 Ιούν 11 09:08 /dev/nvidiactl
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 243,   0 Ιούν 11 09:08 /dev/nvidia-uvm
/dev/nvidia0:    character special (195/0)
/dev/nvidiactl:  character special (195/255)
/dev/nvidia-uvm: character special (243/0)
```

It's weird because I used Ubuntu 16.04 in this machine (at first as dual boot) from the first release of this edition without problems. After removing Windows and installing only Ubuntu 16.04, I have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to fix the problem. I observed that Xorg crashed when I was trying to work in both of my monitors (laptop monitor and external monitor). The reason of the problem is that in my settings I had set my external monitor on the right while my laptop monitor on the left. 
When I changed that, setting the external monitor on the left and the laptop's monitor on the right the problem solved ! Weird, I don't know why but now xorg runs like a charm !

### UPDATE

Finally I disable the laptop's monitor when the external monitor is connected and the problem solved.